# Install a manifest.json on android

Tags: javascript, android, notepad++, manifest

I'm trying to build a Progressive Web App here: https://121eddie.github.io. This involves

- a manifest.json for installing and prompting access rights
- a service worker for offline caching. (It gets installed properly but for some reason never answers offline calls)

The following manifest.json got validated by https://manifest-validator.appspot.com/.

```
{
"name": "Determiner ma position et la partager",
"short_name": "PositionWeb",
"start_url": "/index.html",
"homepage_url":"https://121eddie.github.io/",
"display": "standalone",
"description": "Une application Web Progressive qui permet de connaitre sa position et de la telecharger ou partager, meme en mode offline",
"lang": "fr-FR",
"scope": "/",
"background_color": "lightyellow",
"theme_color": "lightgreen",
"permissions": [
    "geolocation",
    "fileSystem",
    "fileSystem.write",
    "notifications"
],
"icons": [{"src": "icon200.png","sizes": "200x200","type": "image/png"},
{"src": "icon512.png","sizes": "512x512","type": "image/png"}
]
}
```

it is loaded in index.html with

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Yet on Google Chrome I get

```
SytaxError: unexpected token in JSON on position 0
```

Where's the bug?

---

**Update**

I improved the following aspects

1. I added an icon
2. I encoded in utf-8 (instead of ansi)
3. I added a favicon.ico

**Solution**

prevent Notepad++ from automatically adding a space before the first bracket

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was the editor: even when saving in utf-8, Notepad adds a space before the first Bracket "{", thereby making the code invalid.  Be carefull about the choice of your JSON editor!

Comment: This sound like a user error, not a fault with Notepad++.  If Notepad++ added unexpected spaces then there would have been many fault reports issued. Can you provide details of how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN docs on installable pwa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive/Installable_PWAs)

> The bare minimum requirement for a web manifest is name and at least one icon (with src, size and type).

So, at least your manifest lacks of an icon